# Coefficient symmetry of the Laurent expansion of the composition of a function with the Joukowski map

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

In [Sheehan Olver's exposition of how Chebyshev series arise](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rfo3rz24t5iapp/06.pdf?dl=0), he lets $f\in C^\infty[-1,1]$ and defines
$$g(z)=f(J(z))$$
where
$$J(z)=\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$$
is the Joukowsky map. He then claims that the Laurent series expansion of $g$,
$$g(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{g}_kz^k$$
satisfies $\hat{g}_k=\hat{g}_{-k}$. I tried proving this, but kept getting $\hat{g}_k=-\hat{g}_{-k}$:
$$\hat{g}_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{g(z)}{z^{k+1}}\mathrm{d}z=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint g(1/z)(1/z)^{k+1}\mathrm{d}z=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint g(\zeta)\zeta^{k-1}\mathrm{d}\zeta=-\hat{g}_{-k}$$
where the substitution $\zeta=1/z$ was used.

Where am I going wrong in my proof?

<sub>Edit: I initially linked to the wrong PDF. It is corrected now.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where am I going wrong in my proof?

One small but important detail: orientation.

The substitution $\zeta = \frac{1}{z}$ reverses the orientation of the unit circle, for $z$ it was traversed counterclockwise, and for $\zeta$ it then is traversed clockwise. That gives you the sign.

Note that the uniqueness of the Laurent expansion gives the symmetry also without integration, since $g(z) = g(1/z)$, i.e.

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k z^k = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k (1/z)^k = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k z^{-k} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_{-k}z^k,$$

we must have $a_k = a_{-k}$ by the uniqueness of the Laurent expansion.